# jQuery cartTotal result

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason my website is displaying the word "El product(s)" instead "0 product(s)"

Here my actual script with jquery:

```
cartSummary : function(){
                if (jQuery('#catCartSummary .cartSummaryItem').html() != 'Shopping cart is empty.') {
                      var summary = jQuery('#catCartSummary .cartSummaryItem').text().split(" ");
                      // url = $('#user-options .cart a').attr('href');

                      jQuery("span.cartTotal").text(summary[0]);

                }else{

                     jQuery("span.cartTotal").text("0 ");

                }  
            }, //cartSummary

    checkOutBtn : function(){
                var cartTotal =  jQuery("span.cartTotal").text();

                if(cartTotal > 0){
                    jQuery("a.view-cart").css('background-position','0 -26px');
                }

            }, // checkOutBtn
```

My HTML code:

```
<strong><span class="cart-info"><span class="cartTotal"></span> product(s) </span></strong>&nbsp;<a class="view-cart" href="/OrderRetrievev2.aspx">View cart</a>
```

Comment: you are checking for the value 'Shopping cart is empty.' Check if that text is different or it's in another language.

Comment: Could you post more code. How do you populate the value of the cartSummaryItem element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (jQuery('#catCartSummary .cartSummaryItem').html() != 'Shopping cart is empty.')
```

You trying to compare `html()` with `text`, then split `text` and setting `cartTotal`. Please show `cartSummaryItem`.

Comment: Thank, webdeveloper and svillamayor, problem fixed. The text "Shopping cart is empty." is different language.